# DL4j 1.0.0-Beta6 Openblas does not use more than one thread

Tags: deeplearning4j, dl4j

On my testing-server DL4j 1.0.0-Beta6 with Openblas is only using one thread. Initially it was reporting on thread, so I exported OMP_NUM_THREADS=4, which made DL4j log the correct number of threads on startup:

```
[:19:30 CET 2020] org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend      : Loaded [CpuBackend] backend
[:19:30 CET 2020] org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder      : Number of threads used for linear algebra: 4
[:19:30 CET 2020] org.nd4j.nativeblas.Nd4jBlas             : Number of threads used for OpenMP BLAS: 4
[:19:30 CET 2020] o.n.l.a.o.e.DefaultOpExecutioner         : Backend used: [CPU]; OS: [Linux]
[:19:30 CET 2020] o.n.l.a.o.e.DefaultOpExecutioner         : Cores: [4]; Memory: [0.9GB];
[:19:30 CET 2020] o.n.l.a.o.e.DefaultOpExecutioner         : Blas vendor: [OPENBLAS]
[:19:30 CET 2020] o.d.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork      : Starting MultiLayerNetwork with WorkspaceModes set to [training: ENABLED; inference: ENABLED], cacheMode set to [DEVICE]
```

Unfortunetaly it still only uses 100% CPU, instead of the expected 400%. The same application running on my laptop with CUDA is running fine, with nvidia-smi reporting 7x% usage. So it seems to be related to the Openblas setup on the test-server. I remember a while ago with older beta versions the CPU was fully used, which used MKL by default (Which I can't use any more because the server CPU does not have AVX2).

Is there anything wrong with the log above or anything I could check?

Comment: If MKL works fine, I would simply recommend to keep using that. It doesn't require AVX2.

Comment: I got the impression that MKL needs AVX2 from another thread, but its not true. So I tried with MKL and it indeed uses all CPUs. So I was happy until I realized its not any faster than single-threaded openblas.

Something must be wrong. Could it be me because I call fit() manually and not use any of DL4js iterators?

Comment: It's probably because your batch sizes are not big enough.

Comment: I would expect that MKL would not go up to 400% CPU if batch size is too small. Is that assumption incorrect? I will do some more testing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see your source code. File an issue please: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues